# Scroll full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Here's a little code I wrote that would not use fullpage.js
I want to change it to scrollTop instead of position relative and "top": -_.index() * 100 + "%" with overflow:hidden

Please tell me how to do it. I attached the top menu (header-bg) and a search-wrapper.

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TA72K/16/)

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        onLoad();
        NavAnimation();
        DesktopResize();
        $("body").css({
          overflow: 'hidden'
        });

        /*$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > 726) {
                 $('.search-wrapper').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('.search-wrapper').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        }); */  
      });

      function DesktopResize(){
        $(".section, .fullpage, html, body").css({
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%'
        });
      }

function NavAnimation(){
    scroll.call(active, true);
  }

  var active = null;
  function scroll(silent){
    var _;
    if (active === null) {
      _ = $(".section").first();
    } else {
      active.removeClass("active");
      _ = $(this);
    }
    if (_.length === 0) return;
    if (active !== null || silent === false) {
      $(".fullpage").animate({"top": -_.index() * 100 + "%"}, 1000);
    }
    active = _;

  }

  function onLoad() {
      $(".navigation li").click(scroll);
      scroll();
  }

  var wheel = true;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  if (wheel) {
    wheel = false;
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      scroll.call(active.next());
    } else {
      scroll.call(active.prev());
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      wheel = true;
    }, 1000)
  }
});
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
  if (wheel) {
    wheel = false;
    if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
      scroll.call(active.next());
    } else {
      scroll.call(active.prev());
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      wheel = true;
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="header-bg">
      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li id="NavWho">Rules</li>
            <li id="NavMission">Arrivante Miles</li>
            <li id="NavApproach">Prices</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div id="fullpage" class="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <br>
        <br><br>
            <br>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
      <div class="explain">Type your initial<br> flight number here:</div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Example: FR22">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="search">Book transfer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    background: #d8e6e3;
    position: relative;
    }

.section{
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-bg{
  background: #242928;
  color: #879996;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}

.header-bg .header-content{
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-roman";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-content .login{
  background: url("../image/login-ico.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 15px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px 0 0 35px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 30px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-content .navigation{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 486px;
}
 .header-content .navigation ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

.header-content .navigation ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fullpage{
  position: relative;
}

.section{
  padding: 66px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1800px;
}

.section .header-image{
  position: relative;
}

.section .header-image .header-bg-image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 659px;
  background: url("../image/head-1.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.section .header-image .main-logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -120px;
}

.section .search-wrapper{
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.search-wrapper .explain,
.search-wrapper .input,
.search-wrapper .button{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.search-wrapper .explain{
  padding: 26px 0 22px 24px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-roman";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #586664;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #fffce5;
  width: calc(20% - 24px);
}

.search-wrapper .input{
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.search-wrapper .input input{
  border: none;
  padding: 26px 0 11px 26px;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #bcccc9;
  width: calc(100% - 26px);
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-thin";
}

.search-wrapper .button{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-roman";
}

.search-wrapper .button .search{
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-roman";
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff4255;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: So you want to use `scrollTop` instead of *animate top*?

Comment: @Spokey, yes. Animate scrollTop and remove overflow hidden.
But if you remove overflow then scroll (wheel, mousewheel) function does not work properly.

Comment: A JSFiddle would help lots

Comment: @user2808054. added in top of question.

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker,
Change this - $(".fullpage").animate({"top": -_.index() * 100 + "%"}, 1000);- to - scrollTop.
Remove overflow: hidden.

Comment: Then at least make sure your fiddle contains `.fullpage`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, I renamed classes.
http://jsfiddle.net/TA72K/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK still not really sure what you *exactly* want but have a look here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".navigation li").click(function () {
        activeSection = $(this).index();
        scrollMeToSection();
    });
    var activeSection = 0;
    var wheel = true;

    function scrollMeToSection() {
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(window).height() * activeSection)
        }, '1000', 'swing', function () {
            // can do something when finishes animating here.
        });
    }

    $(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (wheel) {
            wheel = false;
            var goingUp = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ? false : true;
            if (activeSection === 0 && goingUp) {
                wheel = true;
                return;
            }
            activeSection = goingUp ? (activeSection - 1) : (activeSection + 1);
            if (activeSection == $('.section').length) {
                activeSection = $('.section').length - 1;
            }
            scrollMeToSection();
            setTimeout(function () {
                wheel = true;
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/yYJ3z/

This works on mousewheel scroll but not on scroll-bar scroll (which is a more than somewhat complex process to manage).

Comment: Great. That is what I need.
Can I write to you for the help?

Comment: Glad it's what you wanted. Write to me? Where? What kind of help!? You can find me on my website. Just google.

Comment: trying to fix scroll in Safari and IE 9-10+... :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, welcome to the world of cross-browser-compatibility :-(

Comment: I had a problem.
I have different blocks. Second block have bigger height then third, and browser scroll window to the half of second. How to avoid this?

Comment: Well this breaks naturally as your demo had them all at `window` height or `height:100%` If you want differing heights, you will have to calculate the heights of all the `sections` first and then make the browser scroll to the combined height of all sections before `activeSection`

Comment: How in your's code check $(.section:last).
If .section last and mousewheel down, scrollTop body offset().top?

Comment: Sorry that makes no sense.

Comment: No sense to scroll body top?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense - I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry.
If we have the last element of ".section" and we trying to scroll down, then we go to the top of site.
It looks like on slider. If last slide, then we clicking on next button, images scrolled to the first slide.

Comment: Just change `activeSection = $('.section').length - 1;` to `activeSection = 0;`

Comment: In header we have a menu. How to do it? - When you scroll through pages (blocks), was given the red color of the text in the menu ("li").

Comment: Great. That is what I need.